# Sort inheritance in z3

Tags: inheritance, z3, z3py

Is there any way to define inheritance between sorts in z3? (I'm using the Python API)

I'm trying to model two different types of events, write events and read events; for each of them I use a Sort (**WriteSort** and **ReadSort**). However I would like to have a "sum" Sort (**EventSort**) that is either a write or a read event.

I'm defining functions with the following domain:

```
f1 = Function('f1', WriteSort, WriteSort, BoolSort())
f2 = Function('f2', ReadSort, ReadSort, BoolSort())
f3 = Function('f3', EventSort, EventSort, BoolSort())
```

One possibility would be to define **EventSort** as and abstract datatype, but then the domain of all my functions should be (**EventSort x EventSort**) and the only way I see to restrict such domain is doing it manually.

Is there anyway to define both **WriteSort** and **ReadSort** as "subsort" of **EventSort**?

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, sub-sorting is not supported by Z3 (or any other SMT solver). You could declare an uninterpreted `Top` sort and use function to embed the subsorts into `Top`, e.g. `box_int(i: Int): Top`, and an inverse function `unbox_int(t: Top): Int`, together with the axiom `forall i: Int :: unbox_int(box_int(i)) = i`.

If you are encoding a type system, one way of encoding subtyping is to introduce an uninterpreted `Type` sort, together with functions `typeOf(o: Object): Type` and `subtype(t1: Type, t2: Type): Bool`, and a transitivity axiom for the subtype relation (and potentially a reflexivity axiom).

A nice discussion of the translation of a type systems to SMTLIB can be found in [The Boogie 2 Type System](https://lara.epfl.ch/w/_media/projects/guru/krml186.pdf) by [Rustan Leino](https://dblp.uni-trier.de/pid/l/KRMLeino.html).

Comment: Could you please repost a direct link to the pdf? This link does not work any more.

Comment: I found it:https://lara.epfl.ch/w/_media/projects/guru/krml186.pdf

Comment: The Boogie 2 Type System by Rustan Leino